Syntax Confusion Using Square Brackets On A Boolean
I am new to Pinescript and confused about the following code. is_sunday is a user-defined boolean. On the third line below, the code specifies is_sunday[1]. I don't understand this. is_sunday is not a collection and not a series variable that use could use the square bracket to access by index value. If anyone can explain this use/syntax, I'd appreciate it. Many thanks.
is_sunday = dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday
if NWOG.settings.show and timeframe.isintraday
    if not is_sunday[1] and is_sunday


What makes you think it is not series? It is indeed of type series.
dayofweek is series int. It will be different on each day. Therefore, dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday will have a different result on each day and you will have history (series) of this check.

I thought of "is_sunday" as being a boolean result of the "dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday" expression (as would be the case in most other languages). Being new to Pine, I didn't realise that the resulting value could be manipulated in this way. IOW, feeding a subscript to it ("is_sunday") that acted on the expression that the result was derived from. Thank you for pointing this ability/feature out. This was not obvious to me.
